# SQL Server Multiple Attribute Indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can i create an index on multiple attributes in sql server, i've been searching for quite a while and i have found no information about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30019/usefulness-of-a-multi-attribute-index

Comment: @JacquesBronkhorst not sure if it is related with Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

When creating the index simply list all the columns which you want to index.

This example creates an index on two columns of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE #peter (a INT, b INT, c VARCHAR(500));

CREATE INDEX IDX_Peter_A_B ON #peter(a, b);
```

You should always test and validate that such index is useful for your queries.